# What would happen for an image deblurring application if the point spread function is under-estimated?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Point spread function (PSF) estimation is an important image processing function. If we want to perform image deconvolution on a blurring image in order to make it clear, PSF estimation is necessary. There are three ways of estimating PSF:

- Perform image deconvolution and PSF estimation in the meantime.
- Select PSF from a range of PSF candidates, and then perform deconvolution. After that analysis of deblurred image is done, and the PSF corresponding to the best deblurred image is selected as the estimated PSF.
- Select image features (line or point) first manually or automatically, and then analyze these features. Based on the relationship between these features and blurring levels, estimate PSF.

Here I prefer to use the third method, and estimate PSF based on edge spread function, an introduction of this method can be seen from [here](http://www.cis.rit.edu/research/thesis/bs/2001/perry/thesis.html). However, my observation of using this method is that the estimated PSF may be smaller than the true PSF. Then my question is that if I use under-estimated PSF for image deconvolution, what would happen. Is it possible to use under-estimated PSF for image deconvolution and obtain a decent but not perfect deconvolution result? Here I assume that the PSF is of 2D Gaussian type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping with your assumption that your PSF is Gaussian, let's look at what deconvolution does.

The deconvolution operation can be thought of as taking the Fourier transform of the image, dividing by the Fourier transform of the PSF, and then taking the inverse Fourier transform to obtain the deconvolved image.

So, now let's consider an image that is a single point. In the spatial domain, it's a 2D Gaussian and your estimate is a narrower 2D Gaussian. In the frequency domain you also have a 2D Gaussian and your estimate is a wider 2D Gaussian. Now for the deconvolution: If your PSF was correct, you would end up with a constant value plane in the frequency space. But you are effectively dividing the narrowing Gaussian by the wider Gaussian. This gives you a very wide Gaussian (the better the guess, the wider the Gaussian).

Good news! A very wide Gaussian in the frequency domain is narrower PSF in the spatial domain. This means estimating PSF with a slightly narrow PSF will help to provide a decent result.

Note, though if your PSF isn't really a Gaussian and you estimate it as such, deconvolution methods may give you ringing artifacts.